# Automating Dependency Injection in Unit Testing

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, dependency-injection, nunit

I have a folder with assemblies that all contain an implementation of a certain interface (different in each assembly). I have written some unit tests for that interface, and would like to automate the task of running the interface tests on each implementation.

I have a working solution that I don't like:

- Write code in the actual test class to load (the assemblies) and instantiate the implementations, store these in a list.
- Write each test to loop through the list of implementations, running its assertions on each.

*What I want instead* is to run all tests on one implementation, then move on to the next to run all tests again, and so on. My thought was to find a way to do something like (programmatically):

- Load the assemblies and instantiate the implementations - like before, but not inside the test class.
- Create an instance of the test class, injecting the next implementation.
- Run the tests.
- Move on to the next implementation, repeating the process.

(I realize that I could be shuffling files around in the file system - like put an assembly in one location > run the test which loads *one* implementation > replace the assembly with the next implementation, and then repeat the process. However, I would like something less crude, if possible.)

I've been looking at the nUnit test-runners (console etc.) for a short cut, but found none so far. Does anyone know if there is a way to achieve what I want using nUnit or any other test suite that can be controlled programmatically? Or maybe there's another way to go about it all, that will satisfy the "what I want" criteria above?

Comment: You may want to consider using the `TestCaseSource` attribute to provide the types / instances of the class you want to test.  You'll need to the the assembly loading etc, but NUnit will then take care of the rest of the plumbing for you.  http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.5.9

Comment: `TestCaseSource` is an option, I agree, but will not achieve the goal of _running each test for one implementation, then moving on to the next implementation, repeating the process_. Having failed to get a good solution out of implementing `IAddin` and `ISuiteBuilder`, I'm currently looking into the `SuiteAttribute` which looks promising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the NUnit [SuiteAttribute](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=suite&r=2.6.3).

This approach involves creating an "umbrella class", like so:

```
namespace Validator {

    public class AllTests {

        [Suite]
        public static IEnumerable Suite {
            get {
                var directory = @"[ImplementationAssembliesPath]";
                var suite = new ArrayList();

                // GetInstances is a method responsible for loading the
                // assemblys and instantiating the implementations to be tested.
                foreach (var instance in GetInstances(directory)) {
                    suite.Add(GetResolvedTest(instance));
                }
                return suite;
            }
        }

        // This part is crucial - this is where I get to inject the 
        // implementations to the test.
        private static Object GetResolvedTest(ICalculator instance) {
            return new CalculatorTests {Calculator = instance};
        }

        [...]

}
```

Note that the test class has a property for injecting the implementation I want. I choose a property injection because the test-runners usually dislike other than default constructors. However, I had to *remove the `TestFixtureAttribute`* from the actual test class (omitted here) to not confuse the Console-Runner on what to run.

Then I created a simple console application to run the NUnit Console-Runner with the `/fixture` argument:

```
namespace TestRunner {

    using System;
    using NUnit.ConsoleRunner;

    internal class Program {

        private static void Main(String[] args) {
            var testDllPath = @"[TestAssemblyPath]/Validator.dll";
            var processArgument = @"/process=Separate";
            var domainArgument = @"/domain=Multiple";
            var runtimeArgument = @"/framework=4.5";
            var shadowArgument = @"/noshadow";
            var fixtureArgument = String.Format(@"/fixture={0}", "[Namespace].AllTests");

            Runner.Main(new[] {
                testDllPath,
                processArgument,
                domainArgument,
                runtimeArgument,
                shadowArgument,
                fixtureArgument
            });

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }

}
```

I would still be interested in hearing your opinion on this, and on alternative solutions.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to test a fixed set of assemblies you don't have to do fancy stuff like moving assemblies or instructing test runners.

Like with normal classes you can use inheritance for your unit test classes. I would suggest that you create an abstract base class which does the heavy lifting for testing implementations of this interface. For each implementation of the interface you can create a new class which inherits from the base class.

The base class can look like this:

```
public class BaseMyInterfaceImplementationTest 
{
    protected MyInterface ClassUnderTest;

    //Add your tests here with the [Test] attribute:
    [Test]
    public void TestScenario1()
    {
        //do your test on ClassUnderTest
    }   
}
```

And the derived classes like this:

```
[TestFixture]
public class Implementation1Tests : BaseMyInterfaceImplementationTest 
{
    [SetUp]
    public void BaseTestInitialize()
    {
        ClassUnderTest = new Implementation1();
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this help in running all tests once for each implementation (from the assemblies, which are not a fixed set, but rather needs to be loaded at runtime)?

Comment: @OskarLindberg you are right, my proposed solution only works if you have a fixed set of implementations.